# How to add a Report PDF to an Acumatica Mail thats going to be send?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report, acumatica, sender

I'm trying to send Mails using a PXAction in Acumatica and untill now i'm able to send mails up to the number of columns i select from a grid i just don't know how to attach the PDF to the Message, there is something like AddAttachment("report.pdf", buffer.ToArray()); but i don't really know how to specify the report (as a PDF) that is going to be attached

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

Report report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("AP642010", null);
if (report == null) return;
parameters["StartCheckNbr"] = payment.ExtRefNbr;
PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(report, parameters, PXSettingProvider.Instance.Default);
 ReportNode repNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(report);

 var streamMgr = new StreamManager();
 string format = ReportProcessor.FilterPdf;

 var renderFilter = ReportProcessor.GetRenderer(format);
 renderFilter.Render(repNode, null, streamMgr);

 streamMgr.MainStream.Flush();
 streamMgr.MainStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
string file = @"C:\Temp\AP642010.pdf";
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string path = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetFileName(file));
var mystream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
sender.AddAttachment(path, mystream.ToArray());`
```

Comment: I need to know how do i generate it too, so if you know how it would be very helpful